# How to get list name through javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I wrote javascript for getting list items but here I'm hard coded list name as "Projects"(my list name). How can I get list name automatically with out hard coding,

```
function DoLogicalDelete()
{

    var clientContext = null;
    var oList = null;
    var oListItem = null;
   //var lstItmIsDeleted = null;

    var itmID = getQuerystring('ID');

    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Projects');


    //var oListItemID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);


    oListItem = oList.getItemById(itmID);                         // getting ID

    clientContext.load(oListItem,"Title", "IsDeleted");            // load items to oListItem


    oListItem.set_item('IsDeleted', true);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 
}
```

Appreciate if anyone help.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you writing this code?

Comment: Hi Vardhaman,Actually added one button(not on ribbon. took sp action button ) to Dispform aspx page. When I click on button , IsDeleted checkbox will change no to yes. Here I want to write this globally thats why I'm asking instead of 'Projects'(my list name) what I have to write?

Answer (score 6):

You could change

```
oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Projects');
```

to

```
oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId)
```

Comment: Where did you get that information? Maybe it is so in SP2010? Since I specifically checked it in display form of a custom list and the property was there in SP2013.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listTitle = _spPageContextInfo.listTitle;
```

Works for forms in 2019 On Prem. Haven't tried in 2013/2016 but I bet it works there too.

Comment: Can confirm is works in SharePoint Online. Thanks for posting - saved me a lot of work!